# TFS 2017 upd 1 - Restore Tfs_Configuration

Tags: tfs

how can I restore the db Tfs_Configuration on a virtual machine restored to a day before the last db I want to restore? If I rename the existing db Tfs_Configuration to restore the new I can no longer find the TFS configuration on the TFS Administration Console side and can not restore the "Tfs_Configuration" and db collection databases. Which procedure or process should I use to update the db Tfs_Configuration?

Comment: Have you looked at the TFS disaster recovery documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the guidance in [Create a backup schedule and plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan), you used the **Scheduled Backups** feature to create your backups. You will use these backups to restore your data.

If you manually configured your backups, you cannot use the **Restore wizard** in **Scheduled Backups** to restore those databases. You must manually restore them using the software you used to back them up.

The easiest way is using the **Restore wizard**. So, you can [Create a backup schedule and plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan) if not yet, then restore data for Team Foundation Server by using the Restore wizard in the administration console in TFS.

Based on your description, your scenario should be [Restore data to the same location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-same-location). You can follow the steps mentioned there to restore the database.